# How to fix vh(viewport unit) css in mobile Safari?

Tags: css, height, mobile-safari, lightbox, viewport-units

I've used vh (viewport units) css in one of my projects but in mobile safari it doesn't work. It seems like Safari doesn't know what to do with vh, but it works fine in other browsers. I would like to make the same effect with or without vh please help me. By the way I'm using facebox. (height:50% doesnt work fine)

html:

```
 <div id="facebox" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block;"> 
       <div class="popup">    
             <div class="body"> 
                  <div class="content_light">
            <div class="Lcontent_left"></div>
                    <div class="Lcontent_right">
                    <div class="Lright_content"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

This is my css:

```
#facebox .popup {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
margin:auto;
margin-top:0%;
  min-height:100vh;
  height:1px;
  border-radius:5px;
}

    #facebox .body {
  padding:0px;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  background: #fff;
  width:100%;
  min-height:100vh;
  height:1px;
  margin:auto;
   border-radius:5px;
}
.Lcontent_left{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:50vh;
    /*min-height:250px;*/
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
.Lcontent_left_fullscreen{
    display:none;
    }
.Lcontent_right{
    float:left;
    text-justify:inter-word;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:50vh;
    background-color:white;
    overflow:auto;
    font-family:"Open Sans",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    }
.Lright_content{
    position:relative;
    width:95%;
    margin:auto;
    margin-left:5px;
    overflow:auto;
    height:50vh;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size:16px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

There's a pretty good answer to this across at CSS Tricks - https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/

```
.my-element {
  height: 100vh; /* Fallback for browsers that do not support Custom Properties */
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
}
```

```
// First we get the viewport height and we multiple it by 1% to get a value for a vh unit
let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
// Then we set the value in the --vh custom property to the root of the document
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use jQuery in order to fix that.

```
$('container').height($(window).height()/2);
```

This works on every browser. Hope it helps.

Comment: do not do this if you're using react

Answer (score 8):

I came across this fix today: https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill
It checks every element for a vh/vw unit and turns it into px.
Well worth checking out I think.

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS Safari 10.3. https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill/issues/82 Having a simple `height: 100vh;` is still 1/4 of the screen. It seems to work (or do nothing) on the desktop.

Answer (score 8):

I used this CSS only hax today and it worked. iOS 8.2 iPhone Safari :

```
html, body {
    ...
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 0px);
    ...
}
```

**Thought:** Using calc seems to get Safari to convert units to px itself. Now my page is correctly full-bleed on Chrome and Safari on iOS.

Comment: This probably won't work on Firefox, Opera, IE, or other non-webkit browsers.

Answer (score 8):

I also had this issue, here is my solution.

This is equals to ***height:100vh***;

```
document.getElementById("your-element").style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
```

You can also use below code with **jQuery**,

```
$('your-element').height(window.innerHeight + 'px');
```

Checked with safari :)

Comment: Due a technical problem i suggest to use jquery css version :  
`$("your-element").css("height",window.innerHeight + "px");`

Answer (score 3):

If you need a fullscreen div on mobile browsers, try using wrapper with fixed position and height set to 100%. Then set 100% height to your popup. You can adjust the position of the wrapper and popup in a way you like with top, left, right, bottom properties, as well as height and width.

These eliminates the problem with mobile browsers address bar autohiding in my case where I had to create a fullscreen popup on mobile chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I found this library very useful: https://github.com/Hiswe/vh-check

It will calculate the offset value for the correct vh, and put it in a css variable so you can use it in the css:

```
.main {
  height: calc(100vh - var(--vh-offset, 0px));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My version is "querySelector" because: if I use class of element "getelementbyid" not worked.
And this way js is most universal if jQuery libraries are not connected.
 `document.querySelector("your-element").style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';`

Answer (score 0):

Related to the answer from @user2394342.

The [provided article](https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/) mentions a [clean css solution](https://allthingssmitty.com/2020/05/11/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/) (no JS code needed) which fixes the vh issue for mobile webkit browsers if you want to **fill the complete available height** (i.e. you use `100vh`):

```
.my-element {
  height: 100vh; /* for non-webkit browsers */
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

Comment: when you use -webkit-fill-available, the children can no longer inhereit the height of the parent. So this is not a good replacement for 100vh