# Flexbox justify-content: space-between not working - footer is just below page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox to position my footer. I would like traditional behavior of the footer - if content is smaller than viewport, it's on the bottom of the screen. If content is larger than viewport, it's below the screen. I have the second option but the first one is causing troubles - instead it is *below* the screen.

I have something like:

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between; min-height: 100vh;">
  <div>header</div>
  <div>main</div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

I would expect the browser to calculate the height of the footer and take that into account when distributing the space between the elements. Didn't happen...

Comment: `min-height` works actually... typo in `minHeigh`?

Comment: As @kukkuz mentioned, you have a typo, still, your _main_ `div` need to fill the remaining space (when there is less content), and for that one generally use `flex: 1`. Check dupe link.

Comment: And do note, when using `100vh` you need to remove the `body` margin, or else you'll get a scroll even with less content.

Comment: I don't think the link you provided solves my question. My question is, why doesn't the code I posted produce my desired result? If I change flex-direction to row, it does, so what's the difference between horizontal and vertical direction?

Comment: Solved! [This article](https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/) describes both the problem and solution. Can you please un-mark this as a duplicate so I can add an answer to my question? @LGSon

Comment: Your question ask how to keep footer at viewport bottom when less content and get pushed down when content overflow. The dupe answer that. The article you refer to shows how to overcome viewport units issues on mobiles, and for that here's another dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223157/how-to-fix-vhviewport-unit-css-in-mobile-safari

Comment: I also commented that `vh` doesn't take body margin into account, and you need to reset it so it doesn't create a scroll when less content. And your code doesn't produce the wanted outcome as it is not properly set, which again, the dupe explain. So no reason to open your post and add yet one more answer, as what you asked is all covered already.

Comment: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/14358-tweening-top-calc-value-not-working-in-safari/